# Android row/column layout design with perfect alignment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i try to design layout with linear layout vertical and horizontal to design multiple row with two column and try to perfect alignment of right column, but columns are shift right and left on left column's word number... how can i fix this problem,help me...

[image]

and my xml is....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#b4cde6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Order Id"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="564789"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Order Datednhgv"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="19/04/2014"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

Change all `LinearLayout` width `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"` like below.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this layout code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#b4cde6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order ID"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="564789"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order Datednhgv"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="19/04/2014"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TableLayout for this kind of designs. You will get more information over here. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for aligned layout. If you are using this layout as a custom layout for listview then remove the second linear layout and use with your listview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#b4cde6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Order ID"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="564789"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Order Datednhgv"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="19/04/2014"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

[image]

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#aee4e4"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Order Id"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="564789"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Order Datednhgv"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="19/04/2014"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create multiple rows, better you can choose **Listview**. Compare to adding multiple layout, Listview is the better choice. [Here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) is the simple sample to handle listview.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your comment, But I in my answer Listview is the key clue, anybody can find sample source for Listview.In addition I had given one of the example link.